# Add a column for multiple databases that have the same table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a similar question I saw on stack exchange but it seemed too complicated for me and I didn't understand it.

So here are are the Databases.

```
Carl_Retail   > Tables > Clothes
Tom_Retail    > Tables > Clothes
Bob_Retail    > Tables > Clothes
Thomas_Retail > Tables > Clothes
```

So for my situation there is many more databases which I don't want to do manually.
For a single table one can do:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;
```

I want to do the same thing but for multiple databases in the "Clothes" Table. The condition is that each database has "_Retail" after it.

I basically want to run a script for every database that ends with the name "_Retail" and add a column in the "Clothes" table called "Socks".

Comment: please specify RDBMS you use. Such manipulations are vendor-specific

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL 2008

Comment: You can use `sp_MSforeachdb` command, please refer the link : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/459536/SQL-Server-Applying-Filter-on-sp-MSforeachDB

Comment: Don't use sp_MSforeachdb.  It's undocumented and unrelaiable.  But that's the right idea.  See, eg [A reliable and flexible replacement for sp_MSforeachdb](https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb)

Comment: Do you realize that sql server 2008 has been fully unsupported for several years now. Even sql server 2012 is no longer supported. It is way past time to get your system upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I know a loop, likely a cursor, is likely to be your first thought. I strongly dislike loops and avoid them whenever possible. And even in this case a loop is not needed. Since you want to change this in all database with _Retail at the end of the name we can use sys.databases and generate some dynamic sql. This should get you really close.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = N''

select @SQL = @SQL + N'if not exists(select *
from ' + quotename(d.name) + N'.sys.columns c
join ' + quotename(d.name) + N'.sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
where t.name = ''table_name''
    and c.name = ''column_name'')alter table ' + quotename(d.name) +  N'.dbo.table_name ADD column_name int;'
from sys.databases d
where d.name like '%[_]Retail'

--use the below to evaluate your dynamic sql
select @SQL

--uncomment the below line when you are comfortable your dynamic sql is correct
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

--EDIT--
Modified to accommodate the possibility that the new column already exists.

Comment: This seems to work except one last problem. How to add one more condition for tables that already have the column? Some tables I may have manually added the socks column. Is there another WHERE CLAUSE for this? The script stops running because some tables have the same name and it won't add it ofcourse

Comment: @TomLarry that wasn't in the original problem description. You would have to expand the dynamic sql here so it checks sys.columns in each database.

Comment: @TomLarry take a look at the last edit. This should now work. This assumes the table exists. If you need to check that you would need to add some additional logic here.

Comment: It actually worked. You are insane! Thanks mate (btw idk if we are supposed to go off topic on this side but u are insane!!)

Comment: If this worked for your situation you might consider marking this as the answer. It lets others know that this worked for you and they might be able to utilize something similar on their own project.